# dateformat validation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function isValidDate(sText) {
    var reDate = /(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/;
    return reDate.test(sText);
}
function validate1() {
    var oInput1 = document.getElementById("txtdate");
    if (isValidDate(oInput1.value)) {
        alert("Valid");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid!");
    }

}
```

I had written code for `dateformat` validations in javascript

and I called this function in textbox as `onkeypress="return validate1(event);"` but **it is not firing**. It is taking date as well as any data including date.

Comment: Better to use a datepicker and set date-format of your wish.

Comment: But the function is _firing_ for me.. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WP37Q/

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the keyword `event` in your onkeypress attribute definition, do you have any errors?

Comment: Check the Javascript console.

Comment: change the function definition from `function validate1()` to `function validate1(e)` and try again.

Comment: i want only date format.it don't  accept any single character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function isValidDate(sText) {
       var reDate = /(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/;
       return reDate.test(sText);
   }
   function validate1() {
       var oInput1 = document.getElementById("txtdate");
       if (isValidDate(oInput1.value)) {
           alert("Valid");
       } else {
           alert("Invalid!");
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is firing fine, suggestion use [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isValidDate(sText) {
           var reDate = /(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/;
           return reDate.test(sText);
       }
       function validate1() {
           var oInput1 = document.getElementById("txtdate");
           if (isValidDate(oInput1.value)) {
               alert("Valid");
           } else {
               alert("Invalid!");
           }

       }
</script>

    <input type="text" id="txtdate" name="txtdate" onkeypress="return validate1(event)">
```